# Splitting vector layer in R

Tags: r, vector, splitting

Is there a way to replicate the Split Vector Layer function from QGIS in R?

I have a Shapefile containing around 20 polygons that I'd like to split into 20 separate files.

I guess since it's in QGIS there would be a solution in Python, but I'd like to integrate it into a R workflow if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can just loop through the individual features and save them like so:

```
library (sf)

dat <- read_sf ("~/data.shp")

for (i in seq_len (nrow (dat)))
{
  fname <- paste0 ("~/split_", i, ".shp")
  write_sf (dat [i, ], fname)
}
```

Comment: The use of ~ always gets me. In 90% of R it's used purely for modeling, and it takes a hot minute to remember that it means 'home directory'.