# R equivalent of ArcMap split by Attributes?

Tags: r, for-loop, split-by-attribute

I have a shapefile of 50 polygons. I've read it into R. Now I want to use R to export 50 shapefiles, one for each polygon. This seems like an intuitive application of [apply](https://www.tutorialkart.com/r-tutorial/act-for-each-row-in-an-r-data-frame/). But I'm having a devil of a time doing it.

I tried a for loop (like [Splitting vector layer in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338244)).

```
STNCODES <- unique(ptsbuf_400@data$STNCODE)
for (i in 1:length(STNCODES)) {
  tmp <- data[ptsbuf_400@data$STNCODE == STNCODES[i], ]
  writeOGR(tmp, dsn=getwd(), STNCODES[i], driver="ESRI Shapefile",
           overwrite_layer=TRUE)
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error in data[ptsbuf_400@data$STNCODE == STNCODES[i], ] :    object of
>   type 'closure' is not subsettable

This seems to be the cause of the error, but I'm at a loss how to fix it:

> data[ptsbuf_400@data$STNCODE == STNCODES[i], ]

Amtrak station data [here](http://osav-usdot.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/3e9daf681b154fb19372044f4d52941a_0)

[Example using SF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338244/splitting-vector-layer-in-r) works--likely there is some difference between the spatial object generated by readOGR/writeOGR and read_sf and write_sf--the latter seems to be a vector, while the sp object is not?

Comment: If you think this is a different question, and are stuck on your code, then just include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't really need to `@data` to get columns in an `sp` object. Its not the root of your problem but it makes things neater:

```
STNCODES <- unique(ptsbuf_400$STNCODE)
```

Second,

```
  tmp <- data[ptsbuf_400@data$STNCODE == STNCODES[i], ]
```

should make a subset of `ptsbuf`, not `data`:

```
  tmp <- ptsbuf[ptsbuf_400$STNCODE == STNCODES[i], ]
```

`data` is an R function, so the error is telling you that you are trying to subset a function (an object of type 'closure') instead of the spatial object you want.

and for good measure here's how to put that in a function:

```
splitByAttributes = function(spdata, codename, dsn=getwd()){
CODES <- unique(spdata[[codename]])
for (i in 1:length(CODES)) {
  tmp <- spdata[spdata[[codename]] == CODES[i], ]
  writeOGR(tmp, dsn=dsn, CODES[i], driver="ESRI Shapefile",
           overwrite_layer=TRUE)
  }
}
```

which makes it easier to test and reuse.

```
> d = data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10),g=paste0("C",runif(10)>.5))
> coordinates(d)=~x+y
> head(d)
              coordinates     g
1  (0.9877652, 0.1615483) CTRUE
2 (0.3598359, 0.06623409) CTRUE
3  (0.5372637, 0.0559466) CTRUE
4   (0.696683, 0.6759665) CTRUE
5  (0.2361368, 0.1350742) CTRUE
6  (0.9232246, 0.8288764) CTRUE
> splitByAttributes(d, "g")
```

That produces two shapefiles that I can then test by reading in:

```
> ctrue = readOGR(".","CTRUE")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "/home/rowlings/Downloads/SO/vrt", layer: "CTRUE"
with 9 features
It has 1 fields
> cfalse = readOGR(".","CFALSE")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "/home/rowlings/Downloads/SO/vrt", layer: "CFALSE"
with 1 features
It has 1 fields
```

9 points in one and only 1 in the other? seems unlikely. what was the original grouping?

```
> table(d$g)

CFALSE  CTRUE 
     1      9
```

Oh well seems its all working.